# Getting Error while Sending automatic email on background

Tags: android

Getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler" while Sending automatic email on background..I have added activation.jar ,additional.jar.mail.jar already ,but getting same error again,,plz tell me proper solution..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to provide more explanation. Like code snippet, stacktrace f your error and how you initializes the mail client

Comment: you have added any automatic error report library ?

Comment: Now  i m not getting any Error ,code Executes successfully,but i m not getting mail in my(Receipient) inbox..

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK makes it very easy to send emails from an application, but unfortunately, that's only if you want to send them via the built-in mailing app. For most situations this works fine, but if you want to send something out and don't want any input/intervention from the user, it's not as easy.

so please follow this link

[http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reply,now i m not getting above error,but i m not getting mail into my inbox though execution done properly..